# Removing dependency from Next.js dynamic bundle

Tags: import, next.js, dynamic-import

When using a Next.js dynamic import. Next.js will bundle the imported module and serve that file.

Let's say that file uses a dependency like `styled-components`, this is already apart of the main app and has been loaded. I'd like a way to omit dependencies from within the dynamically generated bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this only happens when running in Dev mode, if you build for production the bundles are optimized.